# ACTION_UP doesn't work

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to do an app which user can move image... And when the user move it to a certain place, app should do something else... Kinda unlocking...

But the problem is when ACTION_UP statement doesn't work... Any suggestions?

Here's my codes:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private View selected_item = null;
    private int offset_x = 0;
    private int offset_y = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lout);
        vg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                          switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x = (int) event.getX() - offset_x;
                    int y = (int) event.getY() - offset_y;
                    int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - 100;
                    int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - 100;
                    if (x > w)
                        x = w;
                    if (y > h)
                        y = h;
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                            new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    lp.x = x;
                    lp.y = y;
                    selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    offset_x = (int) event.getX();
                    offset_y = (int) event.getY();
                    selected_item = v;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (offset_x < 150 && offset_x > 120 && offset_y < 230
                            && offset_y > 200)
                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                "com.yahya.GeneralTraining.UNLOCKED"));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: When you release your finger is he still over the ImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your implementation is not exactly what you are looking for, you should assign  `offset_x` and `offset_y` values inside `ACTION_UP` instead of `ACTION_DOWN`. Right now it will work like if user started dragging from x(120 to 150) and y(200 to 230) and drop anywhere. Unlock intent will fire, but what you want is drag from anywhere and drop to  x(120 to 150) and y(200 to 230).

So write:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //Are you sure you want event.getActionMasked() ??
    //I use event.getAction() 
    switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       //I don't believe you really need anything to do here
       break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           offset_x = (int) event.getX();
           offset_y = (int) event.getY();
           selected_item = v;
           if (offset_x < 150 && offset_x > 120 && offset_y < 230 && offset_y > 200)
               startActivity(new Intent("com.yahya.GeneralTraining.UNLOCKED"));
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Like this, it's not even move :/ So i guess it should be in ACTION_DOWN... but i also try to put them into ACTION_UP... still not working :/

Comment: are you sure you want event.getActionMasked() ??
i use use event.getAction() .......check edited code

Comment: I just tried your way but it gives "NullPointerException" error at this line:      selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: that problem is related to Layout_Params import .i am considering original question as solved . so you requested to accept answer, because NP exception you can deal by your own .

Comment: I just put a control like below just to see what's going on in ACTION_UP segment... But i saw that this Log never shows up! 

Log.e("SONUC", "SONUC5: " + offset_x + ", " + offset_y);

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to return `true` in your imageView onTouch() callback. For some reason returning false after `ACTION_DOWN` causes you to not get another call with `ACTION_UP`.

Answer (score 2):

your onTouch function must return true. This avoid other listener to take control of the event and mess up your application.